# NOT IN (together with join) query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2014

I have two tables :  `Part`, `OrderLine`:

```
Part (PartNum PK, PartDesc, Price)

OrderLine (OrderNum PK, PartNum PK, QtyOrdered)
```

And I want to find out the parts that were *not* ordered. I think I have a good idea, but I may be missing something;  I think most likely on the syntax. Please check:

```
select Part.PartNum
    ,OrderLine.OrderNum
from OrderLine
inner join Part on OrderLine.PartNum = Part.PartNum
where PartNum not in (
        select distinct (OrderNum)
        from OrderLine
        )
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the parts that were *not* ordered, then you should start with `Part`, not `OrderLine`. When you're thinking about sets, that is the only one that could conceivably have the items you're looking for. Part can be a Superset of ordered parts and OrderLine could easily be a [Subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of parts.

```
SELECT PartName
FROM Part
WHERE PartNum NOT IN (
        SELECT PartNum
        FROM OrderLine
        )
```

More often than not, comparing integers will be far more efficient than strings, so I've changed the `WHERE` clause to look for PartNums, not PartNames.

Comment: Also if you are doing a NOT IN then you don't need a distinct on the subquery.

Comment: @Dave: Don't I have to join with OrderLine first, to be able to refer to it in the inner query?

Comment: No, the subquery is executed independently of the outer query. See here for more info: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3464481/Using-a-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm

Comment: `PartNum` is the PK in `Part`, so the first `DISTINCT` is not needed either. The query can also be written (if you want only the `PartNum` in the result and not any other columns from `Part`) as: `SELECT PartNum FROM Part  EXCEPT  SELECT PartNum FROM OrderLine ;`